# Algorithm for determining solids/holes in a compound Bezier shape

Tags: svg, graphics, bezier

I'm using the [nanovg](https://github.com/memononen/nanovg) library to render a compound Bezier shape, but the [nanosvg](https://github.com/memononen/nanosvg) library doesn't tell me the winding direction, aka the solidity/hole-ness of each subpath in the compound shape.

*What is a mathematical algorithm that will tell me which subpath is solid and which is a hole, given the Bezier points of the subpaths, assuming that all paths are nonintersecting?*

I could compute the area of each subpath, sort by area, and alternative between solid and hole, but this only works if the paths form a subset chain, so drawing this compound shape would not be possible.

[image: compond shape figure]

Comment: technical note: "bezier polygons" don't exist. Polygons are paths consisting of straight line sections, whereas beziers are curves. That might be nitpicking, but you're asking about a technical subject, so getting the terms right makes all the difference. As for "is there an algorithm?" the answer depends on your library. Some libraries treat clockwise/anticlockwise as fill/cutout, some adhere to "opposite direction means opposite fill rule". However, there is no algorithm that can tell you what HAS to be fill/cutout based purely on paths, because that's not a property of paths.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Nice catch, thanks. Also added the assumption that all paths are nonintersecting, so I believe this should be well-defined now. nanovg happens to treat CCW as fill and CW as cutout.

Comment: Can you specify the svg fill rule? If so, set it to even/odd and that should do the trick without any work on your side. If not, set it anyway, just after nanosvg generates your file, using a secondary utlity (or even a string replace).

Comment: why not add the SVG as code so we can see what you really got (sadly SO/SE does not support SVG and PCX images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is the one described in the SVG [fill-rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillRuleProperty) definition. Start from a point and draw one arbitrary ray to infinity (well, a line that ends outside the area you need to consider) and count the path crossings with one of the two methods *nonzero* and *evenodd* described.

**Determining the count of crossings:** Don't try to do this for subpaths in one go, but consider each path segment individually. The majority will have a count of zero, which is fine. [This library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm) has for example a [function](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm#Anchor-intersectBezie-56963) for computing the intersection points between a cubic Bezier and a line. Look at the source code, it is well documented. (Although it is not very clear which stance the author takes on copyright.)

**Determining the path direction:** You only have to determine whether the starting and end point of the segment are left or right of your ray.

- If both are on the same side, count one left-to-right and one right-to-left. (nonzero rule: 0, evenodd rule: +2)
- If the start point is left and the end point is right, either count one left-to-right (+1), or, for a cubic Bezier with three crossings, count two left-to-right and one right-to-left. (nonzero rule: +1, evenodd rule: +3)
- If the start point is right and the end point is left, for one crossing (nonzero rule: -1, evenodd rule: +1) or for three crossings (nonzero rule: -1, evenodd rule: +3)
- If the ray crosses a subpath just at a segment point, you have to avoid counting the crossing twice. The best way to avoid errors is to handle the two segments as if they were one, subtract one from the added count of crossings, and determine the side only for the overall start/end points.

In the end, for *nonzero*, a point is inside if the final count total is not zero. For *evenodd*, it is inside if the final count total is odd.

Comment: Thanks! This is more elegant than I thought, once the cubic solver is out of the way.